# Siesta - Segmentation fault error

Tags: density-functional-theory, siesta, electronic-transport

I am trying to perform a scattering region calculation but I get this error : (from .err file)

```
    [node12:360391] mca_base_component_repository_open: unable to open mca_btl_vader: libxpmem.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (ignored)
    [node12:360389] mca_base_component_repository_open: unable to open mca_btl_vader: libxpmem.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (ignored)
    [node12:360390] mca_base_component_repository_open: unable to open mca_btl_vader: libxpmem.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (ignored)
    [node12:360388] mca_base_component_repository_open: unable to open mca_btl_vader: libxpmem.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (ignored)
    [node14:1273154] mca_base_component_repository_open: unable to open mca_btl_vader: libxpmem.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (ignored)
    [node14:1273153] mca_base_component_repository_open: unable to open mca_btl_vader: libxpmem.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (ignored)
    [node04:2275795] mca_base_component_repository_open: unable to open mca_btl_vader: libxpmem.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (ignored)
    [node04:2275793] mca_base_component_repository_open: unable to open mca_btl_vader: libxpmem.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (ignored)
    [node04:2275795:0:2275795] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address 0x48)
    ==== backtrace (tid:2275795) ====
     0 0x0000000000012cf0 __funlockfile()  :0
     1 0x000000000057bf32 fi_opx_shm_poll_many.constprop.0()  fi_opx_cq_ops_table_non_locking.c:0
     2 0x00000000003f864b fi_opx_cq_read_FI_CQ_FORMAT_TAGGED_0_OFI_RELIABILITY_KIND_ONLOAD_FI_OPX_HDRQ_MASK_2048_0x0018000000000000ull_FI_PROGRESS_MANUAL()  fi_opx_cq_ops_table_non_locking.c:0
     3 0x00000000000051ba ompi_mtl_ofi_progress_no_inline()  ???:0
     4 0x000000000002e20b opal_progress()  ???:0
     5 0x00000000000d6e58 ompi_mpi_init()  ???:0
     6 0x000000000007ac17 MPI_Init_thread()  ???:0
     7 0x0000000000057421 MPI_Init_thread_f08()  ???:0
     8 0x00000000004f8b45 __m_siesta_init_MOD_siesta_init()  ???:0
     9 0x000000000040855f main()  ???:0
    10 0x000000000003ad85 __libc_start_main()  ???:0
    11 0x000000000040862e _start()  ???:0
    =================================
    [node04:2275793:0:2275793] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
    
    Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
    
    Backtrace for this error:
    ==== backtrace (tid:2275793) ====
     0 0x0000000000012cf0 __funlockfile()  :0
     1 0x0000000000668c93 fi_opx_ep_tx_send_internal.constprop.0()  fi_opx_tagged.c:0
     2 0x000000000062bcde fi_opx_tsenddata_0_FI_AV_MAP_0x0018000000000000ull_OFI_RELIABILITY_KIND_ONLOAD()  fi_opx_tagged.c:0
     3 0x000000000000bf14 ompi_mtl_ofi_isend_true()  mtl_ofi_isend_opt.c:0
     4 0x000000000000337b mca_pml_cm_isend()  pml_cm.c:0
     5 0x00000000000a031c ompi_coll_base_bcast_intra_generic()  ???:0
     6 0x000000000000707c ompi_coll_tuned_bcast_intra_dec_fixed()  ???:0
     7 0x0000000000064bd8 MPI_Bcast()  ???:0
     8 0x0000000000051ae3 pmpi_bcast_()  ???:0
     9 0x00000000008fb9d2 __mpi__i4_s_MOD_mpi_bcast_t()  ???:0
    10 0x0000000000898b0f __fdf_MOD_fdf_init()  ???:0
    11 0x00000000004bfb0e reinit_()  ???:0
    12 0x00000000004f7f25 __m_siesta_init_MOD_siesta_init()  ???:0
    13 0x000000000040855f main()  ???:0
    14 0x000000000003ad85 __libc_start_main()  ???:0
    15 0x000000000040862e _start()  ???:0
    =================================
    
    ****Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.****
    
    Backtrace for this error:
    #0  0x15555290dcef in ???
    #1  0x155546500f32 in ???
    #2  0x15554637d64a in ???
    #3  0x15553ea8e1b9 in ???
    #4  0x155551b2720a in ???
    #5  0x155553562e57 in ???
    #6  0x155553506c16 in ???
    #7  0x155553477420 in ???
    #8  0x4f8b44 in ???
    #9  0x40855e in ???
    #10  0x155552570d84 in ???
    #11  0x40862d in ???
    #12  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
    #0  0x15555290dcef in ???
    #1  0x1555465edc93 in ???
    #2  0x1555465b0cdd in ???
    #3  0x15553f2a5f13 in ???
    #4  0x15554400437a in ???
    #5  0x15555352c31b in ???
    #6  0x15553ef7f07b in ???
    #7  0x1555534f0bd7 in ???
    #8  0x155553471ae2 in ???
    #9  0x8fb9d1 in ???
    #10  0x898b0e in ???
    #11  0x4bfb0d in ???
    #12  0x4f7f24 in ???
    #13  0x40855e in ???
    #14  0x155552570d84 in ???
    #15  0x40862d in ???
    #16  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
    a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 0 on node node04 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Input File

```
    SolutionMethod        Transiesta
    
    SystemName  MX scat
    SystemLabel scat
    
    ==================================================
    ==================================================
    # SPECIES AND BASIS
    
    # Number of species 
    NumberOfSpecies 3
    %block ChemicalSpeciesLabel
      1  22 Ti
      2   6 C
      3   8 O
    %endblock ChemicalSpeciesLabel
    
    ==================================================
    ==================================================
    # K-points
    
    %block kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack
     5    0    0    0.0
     0    1    0    0.0
     0    0    50   0.0
    %endblock kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack
    
    ==================================================
    ==================================================
    # Structure
    NumberOfAtoms 360
    NumberOfSpecies 3
    LatticeConstant 1.0 Ang
    %block LatticeVectors
    12.144  0   0
    0   15  0
    0   0   47.3266
    %endblock LatticeVectors
    AtomicCoordinatesFormat  Ang
    %block AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
    ...
    ...
    ...
    %endblock AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
    
    ==================================================
    ==================================================
    # General variables
    
    PAO.BasisSize    SZP
    PAO.EnergyShift  0.05 Ry  
    XC.functional   GGA
    XC.authors      PBE
    PAO.SplitTailNorm  true
    PAO.SplitNorm   0.3
    ElectronicTemperature  100 K 
    MeshCutoff           450. Ry
    SpinPolarized .false.
    
    ==================================================
    ==================================================
    
    DM.MixSCF1   T
    MaxSCFIterations      1000          
    DM.MixingWeight       0.05          
    DM.Tolerance          1.d-4         
    DM.UseSaveDM          true          
    DM.NumberPulay        5
    #TS.MixH               yes
    #Diag.DivideAndConquer  no
    #Diag.ParallelOverK     yes
    
    ==================================================
    ==================================================
    # MD variables
    
    MD.FinalTimeStep 1
    MD.TypeOfRun CG
    MD.NumCGsteps     000
    MD.UseSaveXV      .true.
    
    ==================================================
    ==================================================
    # Output variables
    
    WriteMullikenPop                1
    WriteBands                      .false.
    SaveRho                         .false.
    SaveDeltaRho                    .false.
    SaveHS                          .false.
    SaveElectrostaticPotential      True 
    SaveTotalPotential              no
    WriteCoorXmol                   .true.
    WriteMDXmol                     .true.
    WriteMDhistory                  .false.
    WriteEigenvalues                yes
    
    ==================================================
    ==================================================
    
    # Bias voltage
    TS.Voltage 0.6 eV
    %block TS.ChemPots
      Left
      Right
    %endblock TS.ChemPots
    
    %block TS.ChemPot.Left
      mu V/2
      contour.eq
        begin
          c-Left
          t-Left
        end
    %endblock TS.ChemPot.Left
    %block TS.ChemPot.Right
      mu -V/2
      contour.eq
        begin
          c-Right
          t-Right
        end
    %endblock TS.ChemPot.Right
    
    TS.Elecs.Bulk true
    TS.Elecs.DM.Update none
    TS.Elecs.GF.ReUse false
    TS.ChargeCorrection fermi  
    
    %block TS.Elecs
      Left
      Right
    %endblock TS.Elecs
    
    %block TS.Elec.Left
      TSHS ./elec.TSHS
      chem-pot Left
      semi-inf-dir -a3
      elec-pos begin 1
    %endblock TS.Elec.Left
    
    %block TS.Elec.Right
      TSHS ./elec.TSHS
      chem-pot Right
      semi-inf-dir +a3
      elec-pos end -1
    %endblock TS.Elec.Right
    
    TS.Contours.Eq.Pole 2.5 eV
    %block TS.Contour.c-Left
      part circle
       from   -40.00000 eV + V/2 to -10. kT + V/2
        points 30
         method g-legendre
    %endblock TS.Contour.c-Left
    %block TS.Contour.t-Left
      part tail
       from prev to inf
        points 10
         method g-fermi
    %endblock TS.Contour.t-Left
    %block TS.Contour.c-Right
      part circle
       from   -40.00000 eV - V/2 to -10. kT - V/2
        points 30
         method g-legendre
    %endblock TS.Contour.c-Right
    %block TS.Contour.t-Right
      part tail
       from prev to inf
        points 10
         method g-fermi
    %endblock TS.Contour.t-Right
    
    TS.Contours.nEq.Eta 0.0001 eV
    %block TS.Contours.nEq
      neq
    %endblock TS.Contours.nEq
    %block TS.Contour.nEq.neq
      part line
       from -|V|/2 - 5 kT to |V|/2 + 5 kT
        delta 0.01 eV
         method mid-rule
    %endblock TS.Contour.nEq.neq
    
    TS.Elecs.Neglect.Principal
```

Any help on troubleshooting this error would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post your input file and at least the section immediately above this error from your output file. It is extremely difficult to troubleshoot if you just give us a `segfault` error.

Comment: @HemanthHaridas thank you for the comment. I have added what you have asked.

Comment: Can you do what I mentioned in the answer?

Answer (score 2):

The error file shows that some library of the name `libxpmem.so` is missing, and i would guess that it is required for the computation to proceed. This would usually mean a faulty installation and would require a reinstallation of the package. You can do `ldd siesta` or whatever is your executable to find all the linked shared object files.

Note: A quick google search returned that this usually is an MPI problem.